# JavaScript json multiple keys

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON `var`

```
{
"total":4,
"page":1,
"pagesize":30,
"type":"associated_user",
"items":[
{
"user_id":2727,
"site_name":"Physics",
"user_creation_date":1300894372,
"association_id":"2fbcabe5-cd42-4f5b-821e-2f1475e42ade"
},
{
"user_id":3864,
"site_name":"TeX - LaTeX",
"user_creation_date":1298808016,
"association_id":"2fbcabe5-cd42-4f5b-821e-2f1475e42ade"
},
{
"user_id":5983,
"site_name":"Stack Apps",
"user_creation_date":1301323608,
"association_id":"2fbcabe5-cd42-4f5b-821e-2f1475e42ade"
},
{
"user_id":6260,
"site_name":"English Language and Usage",
"user_creation_date":1300449905,
"association_id":"2fbcabe5-cd42-4f5b-821e-2f1475e42ade"
}
]
}
```

As you can see, there are four `site_name` keys in `items` block. I can access only the first using `items[0].site_name` but how to access the other three one by one?

Comment: what do you get when you use `items[1].site_name`?

Comment: Is this really JSON or is this just a JavaScript object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greetings 
   if i get you right so you need to loop over the object Array  just like this

```
var obj ={
"total":4,
"page":1,
"pagesize":30,
"type":"associated_user",
"items":[
{
"user_id":2727,
"site_name":"Physics",
"user_creation_date":1300894372,
"association_id":"2fbcabe5-cd42-4f5b-821e-2f1475e42ade"
},
{
"user_id":3864,
"site_name":"TeX - LaTeX",
"user_creation_date":1298808016,
"association_id":"2fbcabe5-cd42-4f5b-821e-2f1475e42ade"
},
{
"user_id":5983,
"site_name":"Stack Apps",
"user_creation_date":1301323608,
"association_id":"2fbcabe5-cd42-4f5b-821e-2f1475e42ade"
},
{
"user_id":6260,
"site_name":"English Language and Usage",
"user_creation_date":1300449905,
"association_id":"2fbcabe5-cd42-4f5b-821e-2f1475e42ade"
}
]
};

var objItems = obj.items;
for(var i=0;i<objItems .length;i++)
{
alert(obj.items[i].site_name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all the site name

You need to run a `while loop` to do it dynamically

```
var i=0
while(i<items.length){

var site_name=items[i].site_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this with jquery:

$( jsonvar ).each(function() {
    tempvar = this.site_name;
});

Then that will loop over the items storing the needed segment in 'tempvar'